# Oracle-SQLPLUS

Tags: sqlplus

When I am spooling the record in the textpad it will fetch the record,However the first row is blank.It will dsplay the record from the 2nd line in textpad.Please suggest me how I can remove the first blank row.Ex-It is display record like this:

## first line is blank

column1  column2

---

xyz      abc

I want to remove the first line which is blank(i.e. line with #first line is blank)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting enviroment vars like:

set feedback off verify off heading off pagesize 0 newpage 0